# New ILogger instance for library from IHostedService

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

I have a project implementing .Net Core hosting pattern.

So I have a host builder:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder()
 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
 {
 ...
 })
 .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
 {
     services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SkillsService>();
 })
 .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
 {
logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
     logging.AddConsole();
 });

        await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
    }
```

and a service:

```cs
public class SkillsService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
...
public SkillsService(ILogger<SkillsService> logger)
    {
     ...
    }
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
     ...
    }
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Now, in the StartAsync method, I want to create an instance of a class from my own library and that class is also implementing the ILogger interface. So I need to create a new instance of the Logger with the configuration from the IHostBuilder, but with the category matching the full namespace name of that library, and inject such logger to the class. I've found a lot about creating new LoggerFactory instance and configuring it, but I want to reuse the one already set up by the HostBuilder. How should I do that? There is no LoggerFactory inside the IHostedService.

For logging, I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging namespace.

Thanks for any bits of advice.

George

Comment: just add `ILoggerFactory` as another arg to the constructor in your hostedservice.  DI will hook you up.   Then in the StartAsync() (or whatever) do a loggerFactory.Create<XXXX>() to create a new ilogger

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my knowledge, I had to install some nuggets to enhance Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

- Serilog
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging

and if you want to store the log into a file

- Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File

Let me know if this tip, solve your problem.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not the answer I was seeking. I am completely happy with the logging ability of the Extensions.Logging. What bothers me is the thing, that for the purpose of the service host, there is completely configured LoggerFactory, and I want to utilize it. But of course the service itself doesn´t know anything about it, it gets only the configured logger. But I need another configured logger from that factory for my library. So even using another logging framework doesn´t help me, because, inside the service, I know nothing about logging configuration.